# Custom List Button on Product object is not appearing in the related list

Tags: custom-button, opportunity, page-layout, list-view, product

I created a custom List button on the Product object :

[image]

and added to the list view:

[image]

But I don't see the button on the Opportunity Product related list section:

[image]

Could some body please help on what I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create the custom button under Opportuniy -> Opportunity Product
and not directly under Products.